# Freely available geospatial data for the capital cities in Southeast Asia

Tags: data-request, geospatial, transportation, public-transport, asia

I'm currently looking for the transport (mainly public transport - route lines and stop locations) and urban (public amenities, population density etc) geospatial-data on the capital cities in Southeast Asia. For now, Bangkok and Phnom Penh would be just enough. Any idea where I might find them?

I have already checked the OSM data. For example, while MRT and BTS routes are available for Bangkok, the bus routes there are highly incomplete.

Answer (score 1):

See if this is what you are looking for ?

http://www.diva-gis.org/Data

ESRI has their Open data

http://opendata.arcgis.com/

or you can google it to find them.

Maybe contact universities Geography department and they may have them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I'm surprised that ESRI established such an open data market. Cool.
However, it doesn't really offer the data I need. Moreover, I doubt that the data exists for Bangkok and Phnom Penh.

Answer (score 1):

Spatial datasets for mass transit are usually published by municipal or state / district level governments (if at all), so I think it's going to be tough going in trying to find an open dataset for those cities. This might be worth a look for some of the supporting datasets you're interested in (population density and so forth):

For Cambodia, under Maps and Data (also can get data for Thailand too): https://cambodia.opendevelopmentmekong.net/#!/

And here for Thailand's government spatial respository: http://nsdiportal.gistda.or.th/geonetwork/srv/en/main.home

Your best bet may be to get your hands on some static maps of the transit systems, and georeference and vectorize them yourself. Or use them to update and augment the OSM layers.